# how to increase available space on EC2 machine

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

If I run:

```
$ df -h
```

I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M   26M  370M   7% /run
/dev/xvda1       30G   29G     0 100% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
```

how can I increase the space available to the ubuntu user on this ec2 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a EBS backed EC2 machine -

In order to extend the volume size, follow these simple steps:

1. Login to your AWS console
2. Choose “EC2” from the services list
3. Click on “Volumes” under ELASTIC BLOCK STORE menu (on the left)
4. Choose the volume that you want to resize, right click on “Modify Volume”
5. You’ll see an option window like this one:
   [image]

   6. Set the new size for your EBS volume (in this case i extended an 8GB volume to 20GB)
   7. Click on modify.

[Detailed instructions are here](https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-how-to-extend-aws-ebs-volumes-with-no-downtime-ec7d9e82426e)